# How to split a text string in Microsoft Access using SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, text, split

I have a column (TIMEINT) in a table (Results) in Microsoft Office Access 2013.
The data type of the column is "Short text" and every field is of the type "30-90", "60-1000", "500-900" and so on. I have created to new columns "Start" and "End", where I would like to split the "TIMEINT" column into.

So the question is, how do I seperate the TIMEINT-column by the character "-"? 
In the past I have worked with PostGreSQL, where I have used the split_par()-function, but this isn't working in Access.

/Katrine

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with string manipulations.  I think this is the MS Access version:

```
update results
    set start = cint(left(timeint, instr(timeint, "-") - 1)),
        end = cint(mid(timeint, instr(timeint, "-") + 1))
    where timeint like "*-*";
```